# Symfony2 Errors are displayed in Production mod

Tags: php, symfony, production-environment

I moved my application in production mode in symfony 2 with this cmd Line

`php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

And In my "web/app.php" file

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

I changed false value to true

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

But My application still give me pages error like **DEV mod** ; For example whene i try to access a wrong link a get this page error

[image]

Normaly the page error should be like this
[image]

Comment: If you're using Apache, have you looked to your web/.htaccess file to point to app.php (and not app_dev.php), or if you're using Nginx, you can look to your configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, verify if the `.htaccess` is present in the `web` directory of your app.
Otherwise, take it from [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess) and create it.

Open it and check that URLs are redirected to `/app.php/` .
If you see a line containing `app_dev.php`, change it to `app.php`.

For example, if you see the following line:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app_dev.php/
```

Change it to :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
```

Then, verify your `web/app.php` looks like [default](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app.php) .

Also, the line you given should be :

```
new AppKernel('prod', false')
```

And last, in the vhost of your prod environment, verify you doesn't specify any `index` like `app_dev.php`.
The default `.htaccess` do it for you.

The vhost can be like follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName your.domain
  DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/project/web
  <Directory "/var/www/path/to/project/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope your problem come from one of this common errors.

Comment: @Fox You're welcome. From where was the problem coming ? Your vhost, missing .htaccess, changed `AppKernel('prod', false)` ?

Comment: I changed `AppKernel('prod', false)`, then its work like a charm

Comment: Ok, this parameter corresponds to the debug state. Set it to `false` disable it.

Answer (score 1):

- Check that your virtual host (or the .htaccess) is pointing to the app.php file
- Clear the cache manually deleting the content of the cache folder

  Note that the second parameter of the kernel needs to be false, otherwise the message errors will display anyway.

  $kernel = new AppKernel('prod',false);